# Python: CSV file not read correctly

Tags: python, csv, printing, filereader

I'm trying to read a .csv file and print its contents (lines). It seems to start printing only somewhere in the middle of the file. The contents of the .csv file are:

```
1975,J,Belgium,Finland,0
1975,J,Belgium,France,2
1975,J,Belgium,Germany,0
1975,J,Belgium,Ireland,12
1975,J,Belgium,Israel,1
1975,J,Belgium,Italy,6
1975,J,Belgium,Luxembourg,0
1975,J,Belgium,Malta,7
1975,J,Belgium,Monaco,0
1975,J,Belgium,Norway,0
1975,J,Belgium,Portugal,0
1975,J,Belgium,Spain,4
1975,J,Belgium,Sweden,0
```

This list goes on to this year (2019), the countries also change.
When I run this code:

```
import csv

def read_file(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, "rt", encoding="utf8")
    for l in csv.reader(f):
        print(l)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_file('myfile.csv')
```

I get this output:

```
 'J', 'Iceland', 'The Netherlands', '2']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Iceland', 'Turkey', '0']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Iceland', 'United Kingdom', '4']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Austria', '8']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Belgium', '0']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Bosnia & Herzegovina', '0']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Croatia', '6']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Cyprus', '1']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Estonia', '2']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Finland', '0']
 ['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'France', '0']
```

and so on till the end of the file (year 2019).
Any ideas on why it starts reading at year 1996 and why the first line printed isn't even complete?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you missing a `[` in your question? `'J', 'Iceland', 'The Netherlands', '2']` here?

Comment: No, this is the exact output I get when running the code.

Comment: try with print(str(l))

Comment: I highly doubt this is the output. Looks like you are missing `[`. because `[` here is for list and its not coming from file.

Comment: Thank you, but neither the utf-8 nor the print(str(l)) does the trick. In fact, I get a different result almost every time I run the code. Now, it's us', '1']
['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Estonia', '2']
['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'Finland', '0']
['1996', 'J', 'Ireland', 'France', '0']

Comment: You are getting correct everytime. It looks like printing issue on terminal. How big is your file?. If no restriction i suggest you to use `pandas` to read csv.

Comment: Yes, I found that the problem was in the terminal. The file has 33375 lines. I'll try with pandas, thank you!

Comment: Because file is too big its just buffer problem with terminal. Your code is working correctly. You can use pandas to check dataframe `head` and `tail` to ensure data reading. Also pandas will be useful to check data for any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the script works, Using python3. Which version are you using,

cheers, Damir

```
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Finland', '0']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'France', '2']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Germany', '0']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Ireland', '12']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Israel', '1']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Italy', '6']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Luxembourg', '0']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Malta', '7']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Monaco', '0']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Norway', '0']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Portugal', '0']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Spain', '4']
['1975', 'J', 'Belgium', 'Sweden', '0']
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: Then its odd; I pasted my output. Do you have simple blank (line) space in the file perhaps.

Comment: No, but I found that the problem is in the terminal, my file might be a bit too big. Thank you anyways!